# Disable Algorithm Label

Tags: algorithms, labels, pseudocode

I am using the `\usepackage{pseudocode}` in this code

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \textwidth=4.5in
 \textheight=7.125in
 \usepackage{pseudocode}
 \begin{document}
 \renewcommand{\thepseudocode}{}
 \begin{pseudocode}{m3partition}{a, i, j}
 \CALL {swap}{a[(i+j)/2] , a[j-1]} \\
 \IF a[i] > a[j-1] \  \CALL {swap} {a[i], a[j-1]} \\
 \IF a[i] > a[j] \  \CALL {swap} { a[i], a[j]} \\
 \IF a[j-1] > a[j]  \  \CALL {swap} {a[j-1], a[j]} \\
 \CALL {partition}{a, i+1, j-1}\\
 \end{pseudocode}   
 \end{document}
```

[image]

and when it renders
it will have the `Algorithm` label which I want to remove, is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer this is the full code i have used

Comment: If you have tested you code and it produces the output above, it is quite ok.

Comment: I did and the output is as seen in the above picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Algorithm` string is hard coded in the `pseudocode.sty` file.

You can use the `\xpatchcmd` macro from the `xpatch` package to remove the respective part from the pseudocode environment. You must replace the string twice, because the second occurrence is the one you want to remove:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pseudocode}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\pseudocode}{\bfseries Algorithm \thepseudocode:}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\pseudocode}{\bfseries Algorithm \thepseudocode:}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{pseudocode}{m3partition}{a, i, j}
\CALL {swap}{a[(i+j)/2] , a[j-1]} \\
\IF a[i] > a[j-1] \  \CALL {swap} {a[i], a[j-1]} \\
\IF a[i] > a[j] \  \CALL {swap} { a[i], a[j]} \\
\IF a[j-1] > a[j]  \  \CALL {swap} {a[j-1], a[j]} \\
\CALL {partition}{a, i+1, j-1}\\
\end{pseudocode}
\end{document}
```

[image]